# How to set default sort by value in yii2?

Tags: php, sorting, yii, yii2

Is it possible to sort using value not using column name?

For example,

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['id' => 100]]
    ]);
```

I know i can easily do this with controller or adding params but i want to do it using `search()` function.

By default, sorting works with column name, So, i am finding new workaround for sort by value.

Comment: Explain better your request seems no sense , a sort is  not based on a single value ...

Comment: @scaisEdge. you were getting right. It makes sense, sort based on single value. probably my example is wrong , but idea is correct.

Comment: In your example code, what was the return you expected? Order by id and id equals to 100 (so... no order)? Order by id starting with 100 (and not show the others)? Can you explain better what's your goal here?

Comment: @Clyff. pretty simple, sort by value, forget example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use setSort

```
    $dataProvider->setSort([
         'defaultOrder' => [ 'id' => SORT_ASC],
    ]);
```

otherwise your request is not satifisied this format because in not based on an array of column and order_type.

You can try override this setting the ->orderBy(' FIELD(id, '100', '300', '500')') ;

```
$dataProvider->query->orderBy(' FIELD(id, '100', '300', '500')')
```

Comment: So, this is the limit  for yii2 sort? pretty good idea to use order by field.

Comment: well, still open for more advanced solution.

Comment: This is a good solution, because one can change the sort order from the controller. And thus leave the (gii generated) search model unchanged.